# Not able to make telnet connection to python server

Tags: python, android, tcp, protocols, python-asyncio

I am trying to set up a python server to connect to from an android app written in Java. Because I want a main loop to keep running in the python program I am using Asyncio's transports and protocols.

I've been looking at the documentation on transports and protocols and used the [server example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server) on the bottom of the page. This results in the following code:

```
class ServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))
        
        if message == 'cmd_configure':
            configuration.configuration()
            print('configuration done')

        print('Close the client socket')
        self.transport.close()
        
        

async def connect():
    server = await loop.create_server(
        lambda: ServerProtocol(),
        '192.168.0.157', 65432)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


async def main_cycle(i, o, p):
    while True:
        i, o, p = hard_io.main(i, o, p)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
        
async def main(inp, outp, prevs):        
    task1 = loop.create_task(main_cycle(inp, outp, prevs))
    task2 = loop.create_task(connect())
    await asyncio.wait([task1, task2])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(ins, outs, ins_prev_cycle))
```

When I use the [client example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client) on my other machine the connection seems to work fine. When I try to connect using android studio's emulation and the following Java code it does not work

```
public class ConnectionClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.157");
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 65432);
            System.out.println("connection made");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("failed to establish connection");
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Because I am not even able to connect using telnet from a terminal I have the feeling I am misunderstanding transports and protocols on the server side. What is going wrong in what I am trying to do?
I am just getting started with this(client/server connections), so forgive me if I am missing the obvious answer to my question.

**EDIT**

So this is what happens:

The python server side is running fine without any errors. When I run this code on one machine and run the client example from the transport and protocols documentation on another, the server prints "Connection from {*CLIENT-IP*}", the client sends a message and the server closes the connection. So This means a TCP connection is made and messages between client and server are OK. When I run the Java client code from above instead of the client example from the documentation I would expect the server to print the same result "Connection from {*CLIENT-IP*}". I have not yet written any code in Java to send messages yet, so I don't expect anything more to happen. However, the client prints "TCP Client", "C: Connecting...", then goes to the next line of code: `Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 65432);` and then times out with the following error: `java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.157 (port 65432) from /:: (port 49580): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)`

Because I'm thinking the server is opening a port, I should be able to reach the server using `telnet 192.168.0.157::65432` from a command window as well. When I try this it also fails: `Connecting To 192.168.0.157::65432...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed` So this makes me think I am doing something wrong in the python code on server side?

Comment: *and the following Java code it does not work* - does not work in what way? Does it exit silently or report an error? Or does it just hang without doing anything?

Comment: Also, why are you using the low-level transport/protocol layer? I recommend starting from the [streams example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams) instead. Finally, consider renaming your identifiers so they don't mention an "echo server" because you're not creating an echo server, that's just the example in the docs.

Comment: You're right, I should have changed the identifiers before copying the code in here. It does not work as in, it times out. I will have a look at streams as well, thanks.

Comment: But what did you expect to happen? AFAICT your server waits for some data to arrive, and then tests (incorrectly) whether it received `cmd_configure`. Your Java client doesn't appear to send anything to the socket. Is there more code you're not showing? Also, what does the code print before it times out? You've added the debug prints for a reason, you should use them or at least tell us as much information as possible.

Comment: I have edited the question with a bit more info. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your server probably binds to the localhost interface, but your java code attempts to connect to an external address, 192.168.0.157. The Python client example works because it also connects to 127.0.0.1. You probably need to change `"127.0.0.1"` to `""` in the call to `create_server` to make the it binds to all interfaces, not just localhost.

Comment: Also, the syntax for invoking telnet is `telnet 192.168.0.157 65432`, not `telnet telnet 192.168.0.157::65432`. The latter might be interpreted as a strange host name or possibly an IPv6 address.